# Why sorted() and reversed() are built-in functions and not methods of sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm digging into Python 3.3 now and I wonder why some functions (for example, `sorted()`, `reversed()`) for managing collections/iterable are built-in but some are implemented as methods of collection objects? I can append item to list using method `append()`, but to get a length of it I should using built-in function `len()`. It seems inconsistent to me, but I think I just missing some point in new language.

Comment: `sorted` takes any iterable as its first parameter.   Contrast with `sort` which is a list method.

Comment: I should read FAQ first: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that these decisions were made for human reasons rather than technical reasons.

The reasoning for `len()` versus `obj.length()` is [explained by Guido van Rossum](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm) (Python's Benevolent Dictator For Life):

> First of all, I chose len(x) over x.len() for HCI reasons (def `__len__()` came much later). There are two intertwined reasons actually, both HCI:
>
> (a) For some operations, prefix notation just reads better than postfix — prefix (and infix!) operations have a long tradition in mathematics which likes notations where the visuals help the mathematician thinking about a problem. Compare the easy with which we rewrite a formula like x*(a+b) into x*a + x*b to the clumsiness of doing the same thing using a raw OO notation.
>
> (b) When I read code that says len(x) I know that it is asking for the length of something. This tells me two things: the result is an integer, and the argument is some kind of container. To the contrary, when I read x.len(), I have to already know that x is some kind of container implementing an interface or inheriting from a class that has a standard len(). Witness the confusion we occasionally have when a class that is not implementing a mapping has a get() or keys() method, or something that isn’t a file has a write() method.

He also explains why `sorted()` and `reversed()` aren't methods:

> Also note that many functions are defined in terms of informal interfaces; for example, reversed works on anything that supports random access to items and has a known length. In practice, implementing things like max, sum, map, any, in and others, as built-in functions and operators is actually less code than implementing them as methods for each and every type that needs to support them.

Comment: The last paragraph about `sorted()` and `reversed()` is a good point, but why they don't using something like mixins or even abstract methods for this?

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm coming from C# where collections classes and interfacese are not built into language itself.

Comment: @artvolk: it's a language design decision. Mixins and abstract methods work well in C# and Java but Python relies more on duck typing. If you want a new collection to behave in a certain way, you just add some methods and instances can then be used by various built-in functions.

Comment: At least, that was the case when these design decisions were made. Now that we have ABCs, `reverse()` and `__reversed__()` in fact are mixin methods of `MutableSequence` and `Sequence`. `sorted` still has no point of customization. Maybe because if the `key` parameter is set there's basically nothing that a container can contribute to the process.